# I have a SUM function in my SELECT but don't want it to show

Tags: sql

I want to see the companies which deliver the most sold items in my DB.

Currently i have this Code:

```
SELECT L."Firma", SUM("B"."Anzahl")
FROM "Bestelldetails" B, "Artikel" A, "Lieferanten" L
WHERE L."Lieferanten-Nr" = A."Lieferanten-Nr"
AND A."Artikel-Nr" = B."Artikel-Nr"
GROUP BY L."Firma"
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

The Output that i get:

| Firma | 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Company 1 | 2756 |
| Company 2 | 2377 |
| Company 3 | 2063 |
| ...many more... | ..XXX.. |

The Output that i want:

| Firma |
| --- |
| Company 1 |
| Company 2 |
| Company 3 |
| ...many more... |

[Code with output as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9xfN.png)

But i don't want the row with the number 2 to show. I just want the Company-Names to show. How would i do so?

Comment: Tag spam does not help us help you. I've gone ahead and removed all the conflicting tags. Also [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). [Edit] your question to re-add the *correct* tag(s) for the RDBMS you are *really* using and remove the image and replace it with actual text. Data should also be supplied as text; either as DML and DDL, well formatted tabular `text` or as a markdown table.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @jarlh I wouldn't know how i could make a simpler example with my case. Because i need to join three different Tables together.
The only example on w3school that i found had a very difficult looking example of a `INNER JOIN` so thats why i didn't use the `JOIN`

Comment: That's alright, but we are still waiting for the sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: BTW, I'd consider some other site than w3... Way to many errors at that place.

Comment: @jarlh Okay i added the Table that i get and the one that i want.

Comment: @jarlh What sites do you recommend besides w3?

Comment: Well, the problem is that I don't know - I don't need any basic SQL lessons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply `ORDER BY` the `SUM()`:

```
SELECT L."Firma"
FROM "Bestelldetails" B
JOIN "Artikel" A
  ON A."Artikel-Nr" = B."Artikel-Nr"
JOIN "Lieferanten" L
  ON L."Lieferanten-Nr" = A."Lieferanten-Nr"
GROUP BY L."Firma"
ORDER BY SUM("B"."Anzahl") DESC
```

(Now using proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.)

Comment: Alright i just changed the `SUM` part from the `SELECT` to the `ORDER BY` and it worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select Firma from 
(
SELECT L."Firma", SUM("B"."Anzahl")
FROM "Bestelldetails" B, "Artikel" A, "Lieferanten" L
WHERE L."Lieferanten-Nr" = A."Lieferanten-Nr"
AND A."Artikel-Nr" = B."Artikel-Nr"
GROUP BY L."Firma"
ORDER BY 2 DESC
);
```

Comment: Depending on the RDBMS (as I can't talk for all the products the OP spammed) this would generate an error, as you cannot order data in a derived table without a `TOP`/`OFFSET`/etc. Also you should really address the 1980's syntax in your answer; the ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax has been around for **30 years** now, so there it literally no reason to have not adopt it. `ORDER BY {Ordinal}` can often be frowned upon as well.

Comment: Tried this, sadly got this error:
`[Exception, Error code 30.000, SQLState 42X01] Syntax error: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 9, column 1.`

Comment: This suggestion would also fail on some products requiring an alias for the sub-query (SqlServer, Teradata, etc).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).